# Log does not come out

Tags: xcode, debugging

I am trying to make a log appear using this code.  However I cannot see the log.  xcode just crashes.

```
-(void) deleteMyFiles:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSError *error;

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not Exists");
    }
}
```

Crash Report of xcode

```
Process:         Xcode [3625]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0 (3332.25)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3332025000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 38302662
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [145]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-11-17 12:19:38.805 +0900
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F37)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          58305 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           6
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  62699 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   6
Anonymous UUID:                      2C13D4CB-E939-611C-EA15-933EC101D4E5

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEKit/IDEKit-3591/Framework/Classes/Editor/IDEEditorDocument.m:702
Details:  Autosaving when there is a different document instance registered w/ IDEDocumentController { self:0x7fda77aa62a0:  0  0x00000001099e5f48 -[DVTDocumentLocation(IDESourceControlDocumentLocationAdditions) exportDocumentUsingTemplateDocument:completionBlock:primaryBehavior:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001097ba663 -[IDESourceControlComparisonEditorDataSource documentForPrimaryDocumentLocation:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
```

I think the main reason is that I am using the LLDB debugger but I want to change to GDB but there is no option except LLDB in the edit scheme area.

Comment: Xcode crashes?  Or your app crashes?

Comment: xcode crashes but I just want the log to comeout.

Comment: Can you give any more details on the XCode crash?

Answer (score 0):

GDB is not supported in Xcode 5. Quote from [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW8):

> Important: Xcode 5 does not support use of the LLVM-GCC compiler and the GDB debugger. Existing projects configured to use LLVM-GCC and GDB will be reconfigured to use the LLVM compiler and LLDB debugger when opened by Xcode 5. Please file a bug using bugreporter.apple.com for any issues that prevent you from moving to Xcode 5 for this reason.

Maybe discussion in this [thread @ discussion.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16656450#16656450) helps to fix that crashing problem.